# Is there an easier/generic way of implementing this switch statement?

Tags: java, generics

I am making a small game in which a Player object is able to move around a 2x2 matrix of other objects (DreamObjects, in this context). The Player is able to move onto Space objects. I will later implement other objects; but all extend the parent DreamObject. Now, to implement movement of my Player, I have to always check if the object infront of it is an instance of a certain object. In the code shown below, for each direction the player intends to move in, I check if the object there is an instance of Space; if it is, I swap their locations and update the world. In the future I will add Monsters, stationary objects and etc. The problem I am encountering is the fact that I will repeat a lot of code with the only difference being how I apply arithmetic on the row and columns depending on direction of movement. I was thinking of applying a Generic class, but I am not seeing the implementation since the operation is different for each Direction enum. What do you think? Is there a better way I am not seeing?

```
//returns location as [row, col]
int[] tempLocation = player.getObjectLocation();

switch (direction){
                    case NORTH -> {
                        if (getObjectAt(tempLocation[0] - 1, tempLocation[1]) instanceof Space){
                            this.world[tempLocation[0]][tempLocation[1]] = new Space(player.getDreamLocation());
                            this.world[tempLocation[0]-1][tempLocation[1]] = player;
                            player.changeDreamLocation(-1,0);
                        }
                    }
                    case EAST -> {
                        if (getObjectAt(tempLocation[0], tempLocation[1] + 1) instanceof Space){
                            this.world[tempLocation[0]][tempLocation[1]] = new Space(player.getDreamLocation());
                            this.world[tempLocation[0]][tempLocation[1] + 1] = player;
                            player.changeDreamLocation(0,1);
                        }
                    }
                    case SOUTH -> {
                        if (getObjectAt(tempLocation[0] + 1, tempLocation[1]) instanceof Space){
                            this.world[tempLocation[0]][tempLocation[1]] = new Space(player.getDreamLocation());
                            this.world[tempLocation[0] + 1][tempLocation[1]] = player;
                            player.changeDreamLocation(1,0);
                        }
                    }
                    case WEST -> {
                        if (getObjectAt(tempLocation[0], tempLocation[1] - 1) instanceof Space){
                            this.world[tempLocation[0]][tempLocation[1]] = new Space(player.getDreamLocation());
                            this.world[tempLocation[0]][tempLocation[1] - 1] = player;
                            player.changeDreamLocation(0,-1);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: This kind of questions is about optimizing running code. That's why it is better aked at [codereview.SE]

Comment: Add a method to `DreamObjects` that takes a `player` instance. Move this logic to that new method. `DreamObjects` should be responsible for the logic that happens based on the `DreamObjects` type.

Comment: Ah thank you for letting me know @Jens. I will post there next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your direction constants don't change, and you're already using an `enum`, why not just assign those constants for each `enum` value? Then you don't even need a switch statement.

```
enum Direction {NORTH(-1, 0), SOUTH(1,0), EAST(0, 1), WEST(0,-1);
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Direction (int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

At this point you already have `direction` so `getX()` and `getY()` will have the appropriate offsets for the current direction.

```
int[] tempLocation = player.getObjectLocation();
int playerX = tempLocation[0] + direction.getX();
int playerY = tempLocation[1] + direction.getY();
int dreamLocationX = direction.getX();
int dreamLocationY = direction.getY();
       
    
if (getObjectAt(playerX, playerY) instanceof Space) {
    this.world[tempLocation[0]][tempLocation[1]] = new Space(player.getDreamLocation());
    this.world[playerX][playerY] = player;
    player.changeDreamLocation(dreamLocationX, dreamLocationY);
}
```

In the above example, all you need to do is add the x or y since they are signed values.  You should probably check my constant assignments in the enum, but you get the idea.

Comment: This is really useful. Thank you!

Comment: Just want to make certain you understand that by accepting my answer you unaccept your original choice (only one answer may be accepted).

Comment: Ah shit. True. While both solve my problem, yours allows me to make things a bit more neater. I appreciate both. Thank you @Georg as well

Answer (score 0):

I would extract just the indices in the switch and put everything else in a generic method. You have to define valid initial values for playerX/playerY and dreamLocationX/dreamLocationY:

```
//returns location as [row, col]
int[] tempLocation = player.getObjectLocation();

int playerX = -1;
int playerY = -1;
int dreamLocationX = -1;
int dreamLocationY = -1;

switch (direction) {
    case NORTH:
        playerX = tempLocation[0] - 1;
        playerY = tempLocation[1];
        dreamLocationX = -1;
        dreamLocationY = 0;
        break;
    case EAST:
        playerX = tempLocation[0];
        playerY = tempLocation[1] + 1;
        dreamLocationX = 0;
        dreamLocationY = 1;
        break;
    case SOUTH:
        playerX = tempLocation[0] + 1;
        playerY = tempLocation[1];
        dreamLocationX = 1;
        dreamLocationY = 0;
        break;
    case WEST:
        playerX = tempLocation[0];
        playerY = tempLocation[1] - 1;
        dreamLocationX = 0;
        dreamLocationY = -1;
        break;
}

if (getObjectAt(playerX, playerY) instanceof Space) {
    this.world[tempLocation[0]][tempLocation[1]] = new Space(player.getDreamLocation());
    this.world[playerX][playerY] = player;
    player.changeDreamLocation(dreamLocationX, dreamLocationY);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Georg, I cannot believe this didn't occur to me